# How to make an R function that loops over two lists

Tags: r, function

I have an event **A** that is triggered when the majority of coin tosses in a series of tosses comes up heads. I have an unfair coin and I'd like to see how the likelihood of **A** changes as the number of tosses change and the probability in each toss changes.

This is my function assuming 3 tosses

```
n <- 3
#victory requires majority of tosses heads
#tosses only occur in odd intervals
k <- seq(n/2+.5,n)

victory <- function(n,k,p){
  for (i in p) {
    x <- 0
    for (i in k) {
      x <- x + choose(n, k) * p^k * (1-p)^(n-k)
    } 
    z <- x
    } 
  return(z)
}


p <- seq(0,1,.1)
victory(n,k,p)
```

My hope is the `victory()` function would:

1. find the probability of each of the outcomes where the majority of tosses are heads, given a particular value p
2. sum up those probabilities and add them to a vector z
3. go back and do the same thing given another probability p

I tested this with `n <- 3, k <- c(2,3)` and `p <- (.5,.75)` and the output was 0.75000, 0.84375. I know that the output should've been 0.625, 0.0984375.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get exactly the result you wanted, but maybe can help you along a bit.

When looping in R the vector you are looping through remains unchanged and value you are using to loop changes. For example see the differences in these loops:

```
test <- seq(0,1,length.out = 5)

for ( i in test){
  print(test)
}

for ( i in test){
  print(i)
}

for ( i in 1:length(test)){
  print(test[i])
}
```

when you are iterating you are firstly setting `i` to the first number in `p`, then to the first number in `k` and then using the unchanged vectors.

You are also assigning to z in the first loop of `p` and then writing over it in the second loop.

Try using the below - I am still not getting the answer you say but it might help you find where the error is (printing out along the way or using `debug(victory)` might also be helpful

```
victory <- function(n,k,p){
  z <-list()
  for (i in 1:length(p)) {
    x <- 0
    for (j in 1:length(k)) {
      x <- x + choose(n, k[j]) * p[i]^k[j] * (1-p[i])^(n-k[j])
    } 
    z[i] <- x
  } 
  return(z)
}
```